# why i have to put extra space in before write option selected because it show error if i don't ' option:selected'

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

```
data: {
      product_id: $(this).data('index'),
      product_quantity: $('#select' + theproductid + ' option:selected').text(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken:"{{csrf_token}}",
      action:'post'
    },
```

why in product_quantity where i used option selected i have to put space before option because if i don't put space it show this error

```
product_quantity = int(request.POST.get('product_quantity'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

can anyone explain.

Comment: Why do you think `#select1option:selected` would be a valid selector?

Comment: there is a quantity drop down for product quantity selection that why i used "selected" as an id and after concatenating a variable which is assigned to get the product id and after that i am concatenating the " option:selected" to select the option in  the dropdown

Comment: The space is a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)